# jquery image gallery slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple image gallery like this. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/#image-gallery  When I click a thumbnail image, image element will create and  loading image will appear a little time and created element  will slide in the visible area.At last old image elment will remove.

```
<div id="imageGallery" style="overflow:visible;display:block;">
<div class="preview">
    <div id="content" style="width:640px;height:420px;">
         <img id="main-Image" alt="" src="../../baContent/image1.jpg" style="display:inline; top:0;left:0;" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="../../baContent/image1.jpg"><img alt="Image 1" src="../../baContent/image1-thumb.jpg"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="../../baContent/image2.jpg"><img alt="Image 2" src="../../baContent/image2-thumb.jpg"></a>   
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thumbnail").click(function () {
        $("#mainImage").animate({ "left": "-640px" }, "fast");
        $('#preview').css('background-image', "url('../../baContent/spinner.gif')");
        var img = $("<img style='left:640px;display:none;' />").attr('src', this.href).load(function () {
            $('#mainImage').attr('src', img.attr('src'));
            $('#preview').css('background-image', 'none');
            $(this).parent().prevAll().remove();
            $("#mainImage").animate({ "left": "-640px" }, "fast");
        });

    });

});
```

I wrote a few code but had no success. Any ideas or tutorials?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Sliders are something very common and you can literally find more than 100 releases that you can use. Just Google jQuery Sliders. Or jQuery Slider Tutorial if you want to learn how it's done and practice through making your own implementation of the same.

Comment: @Peter Of course I googled but I want to develop own algorithm.

Comment: Ok, then Google the tutorials, there are plenty. Because you asked for Tutorials. You can learn from their code or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thumbnail").click(function () {
        $('#main-Image').hide();
        $('#preview').css('background-image', "url('../../baContent/spinner.gif')");

        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        var img = $("<img style='left:640px;display:none;' />").attr('src', imgSrc).load(function () {
            $('#main-Image').attr('src', imgSrc);
            $('#preview').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('#main-Image').fadeIn();
        });

        return false;
    });
});​
```

You can add all animations you want.

For a good slider, see http://bxslider.com/.

Comment: @EnzGLKba You just don't know what you want, do you?